# How to prevent calling a non-static function of an uninitialized C++ object

Tags: c++, class, object, static

Below is a minimal example of problem that occurred in a huge legacy project I am currently working on.

I have a main function that should be creating a new object ob a global object pointer `B* B`.
Because of a configuration error this was not done and the non-static method `b->do_something()` was called.
My expectation would be that this leads to a segmentation fault when doing so.

The code does create a segmentation fault but only when comparing `a == nullptr`.
This was extremely confusing to me because I was looking for problems with the initialization of `a`.
I was not aware that calling a non-static method of an object is possible even when this object was never  initialized.

My question is how to prevent this confusion in the future? So how do I crash the execution when calling a non-static method of a NULL object?

Possible solutions that do not satisfy me yet:

- Wrapping every call to `b->do_something()` with `if(b != nullptr)`

  - Very verbose
- Changing `do_something()` to `if (&a == nullptr)`

  - Works but flagged by clang-tidy (CI check fails)
  - According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099882/checking-for-a-null-object-in-c) a `"A reference can not be NULL"`
- Extending `do_something()` with `if (this == nullptr || a == nullptr)`

  - Works but flagged by clang-tidy (CI check fails)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdexcept>

class A {};

class B {
    A *a = nullptr;
public:
    B(){
        // Sometimes doing this
        a = new A();
    }
    void do_something() {
        if(a == nullptr){ // SegFault appears here because B was never created and accessing this->a evaluates to nullptr->a
            throw std::runtime_error("Error");
        } else {
            printf("Doing Something");
        }
    } 
};


// Global variable
B *b;

int main()
{
    // Long code that should have called:
    // b = new B();
    b->do_something();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not so much that `B` was not constructed as much as `b` is not assigned to anything. As a global variable, it should initially be null. You could try `if (b) b->do_something();`.

Comment: Ideally (for safety), each pointer access should be checked. (once checked, you might pass by reference instead of pointer to avoid extra check).

Comment: Related : [Why doesn't the OS crash if I dereference a null pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394582/why-doesnt-the-os-crash-if-i-dereference-a-null-pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent a user from all possible mistakes and most of the time it is futile to even try (this isnt Java ;). Thou shall not call a member on a non-initialized pointer (actually in your code it is initialized because it is global, but with `nullptr`). Thats not specific to your class, but something one has to consider always when using pointers.

However, there are ways to mitigate the problem. You could make `B::do_something` private and be-friend a free function:

```
void do_something(B* b) {
    if (b) b->do_something();
}
```

Its not very clear from your minimal example, but if `do_something` can be implemented as non-member, then you do not need the member function in the first place.

> My question is how to prevent this confusion in the future? So how do I crash the execution when calling a non-static method of a NULL object?

There is no portable way to do that. Calling a member function on a `nullptr` is undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including it appears to work. If you remove the check for `a` being `nullptr` then `do_something` is actually not using `this` and most probably will appear to work with most compilers.

Checking `this != nullptr` inside the method is also no help, because once the call is made, you are already in undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! You are right `do_something` could be implemented as a non-member function. I just liked the "Java-Style" object approach to it. But if it can lead to such debugging issues I might need to change my mind on it.

Comment: @Kaio1012 as I wrote, the problem is not with your class, the problem is with someone writing `b->do_something()` without being certain that `b` points to an object, and thats not something you are in control of.

Comment: You are completely right, I was just not expecting that.
Maybe one additional question what difference does it then make adding the static keyword from a compiled program view? Is there more to it then a Compiler error when using `this` in that function?

Comment: @Kaio1012 be careful with [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static), it has different meaning depending on context. A static method belongs to the class while a non static method belongs to instances, ie there is no `this` that you could use in a static method

Comment: Okay, got it! Thank you very much for your help :)